# how to return an image from the clipboard in Maui?

Tags: c#, clipboard, maui, .net-7.0

The Clipboard class in MAUI is very thin compared to the similar class in WPF,
It can uses just to return text,
how can you return an image from the clipboard in MAUI?

editor.Text += await Clipboard.Default.GetTextAsync()

Using the Clipboard class I was able to return only text,
Unable to get a picture

Comment: You probably either want to roll something of your own or encode/decode the image in Base64

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did not find a suitable code for this in MAUI.

Comment: You can refer to the official doc about [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/data/clipboard?view=net-maui-7.0). It said that with this interface, you can copy and paste text to and from the system clipboard. Clipboard can only return text, not image.

Comment: blazor and Maui are stupid in this case .. we can use drunken JavaScript ... lol